# How to write Zend db select with OR condition inside AND condition

Tags: zend-framework

Can someone guide me to write a query like below using Zend db select :

```
SELECT `tbl_md_users`.* 
FROM `tbl_md_users` 
WHERE 
      user_type <> 'TYPE1')
AND (first_name LIKE '%tom%' OR last_name LIKE '%tom%' OR user_name LIKE '%tom%')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wanted

```
SELECT `tbl_md_users`.* 
FROM `tbl_md_users` 
WHERE 
  user_type <> 'TYPE1')
AND (first_name LIKE '%tom%' OR first_name LIKE '%dick%' OR first_name LIKE '%harry%')
```

then the first answer doesn't work

I used Zend_Db_Expr instead

```
$likeTom = new Zend_Db_Expr("first_name LIKE '%tom%'");
$likeDick = new Zend_Db_Expr("first_name LIKE '%dick%'");
$likeHarry = new Zend_Db_Expr("first_name LIKE '%harry%'");

$query = $database->select ()
    ->from ('tbl_md_users')
    ->where ('user_type <> ?', 'TYPE1')
    ->where ("{$likeTom} OR {$likeDick} OR {$likeHarry}");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    $query = $database->select ()
        ->from ('tbl_md_users')
        ->where ('user_type <> ?', 'TYPE1')
        ->where ("first_name LIKE '%?%' OR last_name LIKE '%?%' OR user_name LIKE '%?%'", 'tom');
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems the easiest workaround for this as Zend_Db_Select don't have their own methods to write above requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The current, up-to-date solution is to call nest() and unnest() in the where clause:

```
$select->where
    ->nest()
        ->equalTo('column1', 1)
        ->or
        ->equalTo('column2', 2)
    ->unnest()
    ->and
    ->equalTo('column3', 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to use Zend_Db_Select for this. You could use

```
$this->table->getAdapter()->quoteInto()
```

To write an custom query.

Comment: I was looking for a way to do this using Zend methods, but as you mentioned they don't support that, I have to do a workaround as you suggested, anyway thanks.